# Prevent scrolling with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

How can I prevent an HTML page from scrolling when arrow keys are pressed if an iframe inside it is focused?

I'm gettting this error in Chrome

The iframe is focused, I know its focused. The parent scrolls anyway.

Comment: Do you have control over the content in the iframe?

Comment: yes, and its on the same domain

Comment: IE 6+, FF3+, Chrome: all of them does what you've just said by default. I click on the iframe and press arrow down. The iframe scrolls the page doesn't. What do you want?

Comment: `not tested yet solution:` CSS [overscroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior) - not supported by IE, Safari(Mac/iOS), but seems that WebKit will implement it in future

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following code inside the iframe document will prevent it from scrolling:

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var keyCode = evt.keyCode;
    if (keyCode >= 37 && keyCode <= 40) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: that will prevent the iframe from scrolling, but i want to prevent the page from scrolling.

Comment: But if the iframe is focussed, how can arrow keys be affecting the parent document?

Comment: It's because the way he focus it doesn't work as it should. My answer provide him with the code to fix that issue.

Answer (score 1):

This code does the trick:

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function focusOnIframe(iFrameID) {
    if (frames[iFrameID]!=undefined)
      frames[iFrameID].focus(); // Works in all browser, except Firefox
    else
      document.getElementById(iFrameID).focus();  // Works in Firefox
  }
</script>
```

**HTML (example)**

```
<input type="button" id="setfocus" value="Set focus" onclick="focusOnIframe('myiframe')" />

<p>Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br /></p>  <!-- Just some filler -->

<iframe id="myiframe" src="yourpage.html"></iframe>

<p>Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br />Bla<br /></p>  <!-- Just some filler -->
```

I've tested it in Firefox 3.6.6, Iron 5.0.380, Opera 10.60, IE 6 and IE 8.

Comment: you understand that the question involves scrolling, right? not focusing?

Comment: The problem is that your focus isn't working, correct? I.e. when the iframe is focused and you use the arrow keys, it scrolls the parent. The above code sets the focus and the parent doesn't scroll.

Comment: And when you use up and down key, the parent scrolls, correct?

Comment: From skimming over the text and having a similar problem: I think the issue is that scrollbars on a page element "spill over" to the body. When you reach the bottom of the stuff you're scrolling, the body scrolls next. (Which is completely counter-intuitive imho).

Comment: This don't solve anything, problem still!

Answer (score 0):

Answer for someone with no access to source of page loaded to the iframe:

I resolved the problem with `scroll` event propagating to parent element (main html document) by dividing whole page to 2 `div`s with CSS `position:fixed`, 1st with whole html page (parent) and 2nd with iframe only, like dividing screen to halfs and seeing 2 browser windows on split screen.
Or more flexible upgrade: Make the 1st `div`'s CSS `width:100vw;height:100vh;` (+ finetune CSS `top|left|bottom|right`) and 2nd `div` resizable by CSS [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize) (`resize:vertical|horizontal|both`) or any smarter JS code (eg. [jQueryUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784574/a-full-page-layout-with-resizable-panes-using-jquery-ui))

Answer (score -1):

This works except IE:

```
window.top.document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var keyCode = evt.keyCode;
    if (keyCode >= 37 && keyCode <= 40) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can prevent scrolling with the arrow keys using the following code:

```
var objImage= null;

            function getKeyAndMove(e){

            var idtestor = document.getElementById('idPlacer2').value; 
                objImage=  document.getElementById(idtestor);               
                objImage.style.position='relative';


                var key_code=e.which||e.keyCode;
                switch(key_code){
                    case 37: //left arrow key
                        moveLeft();
e.preventDefault(); 
                        break;
                    case 38: //Up arrow key
                        moveUp();
e.preventDefault(); break;
                        break;
                    case 39: //right arrow key
                        moveRight();
e.preventDefault(); 
                        break;
                    case 40: //down arrow key
                        moveDown();
e.preventDefault(); break;
                        break;                      
                }
            }
            function moveLeft(){
                objImage.style.left=parseInt(objImage.style.left)-5 +'px';
window.scrollBy(-5, 0);
            }
            function moveUp(){
                objImage.style.top=parseInt(objImage.style.top)-5 +'px';
window.scrollBy(0, -5);
            }
            function moveRight(){
                objImage.style.left=parseInt(objImage.style.left)+5 +'px';
window.scrollBy(5, 0);
            }k`a`
            function moveDown(){
                objImage.style.top=parseInt(objImage.style.top)+5 +'px';
window.scrollBy(0, 5);
            }
```