# Prevent main window from scrolling when using the arrow keys on a Facebook Application

Tags: javascript, facebook, events, iframe, scroll

I am developing a Facebook canvas application. There are events attached to the arrow keys, however when up or down arrow keys are pressed, the main window (facebook's window) starts to scroll, which is **unwanted behavior**. The iframe itself has no scrollbars. I am focusing the iframe with the mouse, but still pressing the arrow keys causes the main window to scroll. I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165246/prevent-parent-page-from-scrolling-when-mouse-is-over-embedded-iframe-in-firefox) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208021/prevent-scrolling-with-arrow-keys) thread but nothing works for me.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why he downvoted the question?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. Facebook JavaScript SDK has a method `scrollTo`, which allows you to control the scroll position of the main window - `FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);` [More info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo)